# Font awesome not working on localhost

Tags: font-awesome

I've recently changed computer and now when running my site locally all the font-awesome icons are replaced by boxes or other characters. This happens cross browser.

My first thought was the FA files were not being linked to correctly. I checked and they being linked to. The source of the page is also identical to my previous computer (where it still works). The problem also persists if I link to the CDN rather than local files.

I am now using linux mint rather than OSX and tried searching in relation to that but all of the results suggest it works locally but not remotely.

The server is the one provided by the Pyramid web application so it's not an apache/nginx problem.

Where should I be looking next or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but I need to ask it: are your fa files in the same directory as before?

Comment: are you serving via localhost or just looking at the files directly on your computer? I've had similar issues with the latter.

Comment: @GabrielIlharco: Sensible question, yes they are. Additionally if I link to the CDN I get the same issue.

Comment: @ronan_mac: Localhost (the web framework has a web-server as part of it) but the issue persists if I link to the CDN which suggests it's not the location of the files themselves, just it being localhost.

Comment: Using the network tab in your browser developer tools, can you see the request being made? If so, you can check the correctness of the url, response code etc.

Comment: @ronan_mac Thank you for fixing my problem. The file was cached to an old location (not sure why) and seeing it was going there I was able to refresh it all properly (rebuild web-app and restart framework server) and now it works properly. Thank you :)

Comment: This is really silly but IE requires the font files to be cacheable (this issue is documented in the font awesome repo)! I didn't set a cache value because I was still in the midst of pushing to production, and the font didn't show up because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this option will work. If its a downloaded template

font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot@v=4.2.0

**Rename the filename like**

**font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot**

same like for all files the version for ttf,woff,eot@
refer the image file also[image]